# Pass data between Viewer and Editor web parts

Tags: web-part

I'm writing my first web parts for SharePoint 2010. I have two web parts, a viewer and an editor. In the viewer web part I have an edit button that when the user clciks on I want to populate the separate editor web part. What approach should I use to link web parts in this manner?

Comment: Do you mean "Page Viewer Web Part" and "Content Editor Web Part"?

Comment: No both my viewer and editor web parts are custom ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are dedicated [web part connectors](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx#BM1) precisely for this purpose.